# How do I pass a value extracted from an API to a variable in CSV file in Jmeter?

Tags: json, csv, variables, jmeter

E.g.
API A has this response and is using the Json extractor to get value of "location"

```
{
   "customer":[
      {
         "name": John,
         "age": 21,
         "location": USA,
      },
      {
         "name": Jane,
         "age": 32,
         "location": Canada,
      }
   ]
}
```

The CSV data set config has been set up and in CSV file, it has the ${location} variable

| Name | Information |
| --- | --- |
| John | "Info": [{"location": "${location}","phone": "99999"}] |
| Jane | "Info": [{"location": "${location}","phone": "22231"}] |

API B needs to get the following request

```
{
   "Contact":[
      {
         ${information}
      }
   ]
}
```

But instead, I still receive without any value for ${location}

```
{
   "Contact":[
      {
         "Info": [{"location": "${location}","phone": "99999"}]
      }
   ]
}
```

Expecting for the first row:

```
{
   "Contact":[
      {
         "Info": [{"location": "USA","phone": "99999"}]
      }
   ]
}
```

And then the next iteration would do the same thing to Jane etc...

Is there a way to pass the location value from API A to the CSV and pass the information including the location to the API B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the reference variable from the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

```
{
   "Contact":[
      {
        ${__eval(${information})}
      }
   ]
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)